# Read custom elements from rss using Feedzirra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing, rss, feedzirra

i´m using feedzirra to fetch and parse a document with the following structure:

```
<item>
    <title>Title</title>
    <description>Ddescription</description>
    <date>2014-02-01 20:00:00</date>
    <durationMinutes>40</durationMinutes>
    <sessionGuid>f09c385khll5-5edc-4c8a-8370-1027ac7cb2ce</sessionGuid>
    <eventGuid>1d53fac2-a553-46b2-a72323s</eventGuid>
    <sessionID>782235</sessionID>
</item>
```

When looping through the entries, entry.title and entry.description give me access to those elements, but i cannot get the rest.

This is the code for fetching and parsing:

```
feed = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse("http://localhost/sessionallrss-21Dec.xml")
    feed.entries.each do |entry|
      unless exists? Event.find_by_guid(:guid)
        event = Event.new
        event.title = entry.title
        event.description = entry.description
        event.sessionGuid = entry.sessionGuid
        event.durationMinutes = entry.durationMinutes
        event.save
      end
    end
```

How do i get the value for custom named elements like "durationMinutes" or "sessionGuid"?

Comment: Do any errors appear? Looking at the FeedZirra docs, it seems you're able to access any tag in the feed? Can you give us code with how you're parsing the feed?

Comment: Just updated the question above and add it, Rich.

Comment: Hmmm, have you tried removing this line: `unless exists? Event.find_by_guid(:guid)`? Although I don't imagine it to be an issue

Comment: Actually playing with FeedZirra now, so will give you some updates if I run into a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried inspecting the entry object to see if it has the attributes by different names? (puts entry.inspect)

If the elements/attributes are missing from the inspection, you can add them into the parser like so:

```
Feedjira::Feed.add_common_feed_entry_element('durationMinutes')
Feedjira::Feed.add_common_feed_entry_element('sessionGui')
```

References:

- http://feedjira.com/extending.html
- http://www.rubydoc.info/github/feedjira/feedjira/Feedjira/Feed#add_common_feed_entry_element-class_method